# CSS: 2 row layout, scroll each row individually only if combined height is over 100%

Tags: css, flexbox

The goal is to have two containers stacked vertically which take as little space as possible but grow as needed and scroll individually if they can't both fit on the screen. More precisely, there are three main states that should define their layout:

1. If their combined height is < 100%, both will be their natural height, no scrolling
2. If their combined height is > 100% and only one of them is larger than 50%, the smaller one should be its natural height and the larger one should shrink to the remaining size with a scroll bar
3. If their combined height is > 100%, and both are larger than 50%, they should both be 50% with scrollbars

The html below illustrates these examples, but the CSS does not accomplish the requirements.

1. Works fine.
2. Even though the first part is less than 50%, it shrinks a little to accommodate part 2, so both have scroll bars. Only the second row should have a scroll bar.
3. Neither can completely fit, but instead of sharing the space equally, they both shrink a proportional amount. They should both be 50% height

I imagine that this can be accomplished with Javascript, but I'm hoping that a CSS only solution exists.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgdXwv

```css
.container {
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.part {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Visual styling for the examples */
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    /* visual styling */
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.app {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.part li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

li {
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
}

.part {
    width: 100%;
}

.part-1 li {
    background-color: goldenrod;
}

.part-2 li {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!--
   
<div class="app">
<div class="container">
  <ol class="part part-1">
    <li></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="part part-2">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ol class="part part-1">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="part part-2">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ol class="part part-1">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="part part-2">
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>    
  </ol>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `max-height: 50%` to `part` class

Comment: @Soothran Part should not have a max-height of 50%, though. If one part has a natural height of 60% and another has a natural height of 20%, there should be no scrolling at all. Limiting them to 50% would introduce a scrollbar when one is not needed.

Comment: Pretty sure you're gonna need JS for this. You have div that *can* be over 50% tall but at the same time you need it to have a max-height of 50%. That's a JS issue if ever I saw one.

Comment: @Paulie_D That was my fear :-(